# Connection refused when trying to connect with an external IP

Tags: java, networking

I've been working on a little server/client project and I'm encountering a little problem which is hindering my progress.

I think I nailed the core the programs (the client and the server) and I managed to connect the two using `localhost` but when I try connecting through my external IP I get an exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
networking.Client.run(Client.java:183)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Initially I tried using port 10 but found out ports between 0 and 1023 don't work on Macs for some reason so I picked a port outside that range. Connecting with `localhost` worked but when I tried connecting with my external IP (just like a normal user would), I got that exception. My ports are forwarded properly and running `sudo lsof -i tcp -nP` (`netstat` for Macs) will show that in fact my server is actually listening on the correct port. This is leading me to believe that the problem might be with my client but I really don't know.

Here is the `sudo lsof -i tcp -nP` output from Terminal.app:

```
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java      35423 MeshulamSilk   41u  IPv6 0xc949f3cdb29dfdcd      0t0  TCP *:63370 (LISTEN)
java      35423 MeshulamSilk   42u  IPv6 0xc949f3cdbbf1b96d      0t0  TCP [::1]:63992->[::1]:63991 (TIME_WAIT)
```

I know these posts get kinda messy so I uploaded the code to Gist. If anyone would like me to add it here let me know and I will.

[The code for both the server and client can be found here](https://gist.github.com/moomoohk/5486070).

Some things to note:

- MooConsole is a library I wrote which provides a console for exported programs. I use it in both my client and server to display text.
- MooCommands is another one of my libraries which represents a command you can run from the console.
- SocketThread is a class which handles new connections. This enables the server to have multiple clients connected at the same time. It extends `java.lang.Thread`. I don't think it's causing the issue so I'm not including it but I can if it's necessary.
- `Operations.DISCONNECT` is an enum constant which represents disconnection.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or what I'm simply not doing as well as anything else please let me know, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Firewall?  Permissions?  The Mac OS may be actively refusing connections on the supplied port

Comment: I tried it on Windows and got the same issue. I don't think it's an OS problem.

Comment: Could still be a firewall issue.  Are you trying to connect from within the local network or externally (from the web/VPN)

Comment: I tried connecting to a server on my computer from my computer, connecting to an external server from my computer and having someone external connect to a server on my computer. None worked.

If it is a firewall issue: How would I tackle it?

Comment: Okay, so, are you trying to connect from a PC on the same, internal, local network, or are they trying to connect from the outside world.  Have you disabled the fire wall (temporarily)? Does the server allow incoming connections on the port you are listening to?

Comment: I tried all the scenarios you described, and no I haven't tried disabling my firewall... It didn't occur to me, I'll try it now. And yes the server is listening just fine, I can connect using localhost.

Comment: Turns out my firewall was already off. Even then, forcing users to disable their firewalls for my program to work isn't a proper solution.

Comment: Have you setup port triggering on your router?

Comment: `My ports are forwarded properly and running sudo lsof -i tcp -nP (netstat for Macs) will show that in fact my server is actually listening on the correct port.`

Comment: The `connection refused` message is definitely caused by the server. I am not familiar with the Unix command `lsof` but have you tried using an online port scanner to see if it reports the connection as being open? Another obvious suggestion is to check if your client is connecting to the correct IP.

Comment: Similair question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246151/java-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused.

Comment: I saw that question but it didn't help me at all so I thought I'd resubmit and hope for different answers. I tried http://canyouseeme.org and tested the port. It appears to be fine with no firewall blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on Mac, but based on lsof's output, it seems like your program is binding on  IPv6 only address. It'll work fine on localhost but if you try a public ip address (and use IPv4) it can be the source of your problem. As for the port number, on UNIX like OS you need to have root access to user ports below 1024. Any way, you should try to disable IPv6 on your Mac and see if the problem continues.